# TypeError - 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' ao iterar sobre lista

Tags: python, lista

**Problema:**
Escreva uma função que aceite uma lista de números inteiros e retorne uma lista que é a versão sorteada(de ordem ascendente) da lista original.(Lista original não deve ser modificada). Não pode usar a função built-in sort() ou sorted().

**Eis a minha solução:**

```
1 def func(i):
2     i_copy = []
3     for elem in i:
4         i_copy.append(elem)
5     for y in range(0, len(i_copy)):
6         for x in i_copy:
7             if x < i_copy[y]:
8                 aux = x
9                 i_copy[y] = x
10                 i_copy = aux
11     return i_copy
```

Dá o seguinte erro:

> Error in evaluating function: TypeError at line 7
>   'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Alguém me ajuda a resolver o problema?

Não percebo porque é que o atributo `__getitem__` tem a ver com o problema ou porque é que eu preciso dele, e porque é que esta linha em específico tem de errado.

Answer (score 1):

o **getitem** é um método que todo objeto em python possui para que você possa fazer chamadas dinâmicas dos métodos e recolher atributos através de uma string. Ex.

```
>> to_upper = "string"
>> to_upper.__getattribute__("upper")()
STRING
```

o erro do seu código é quando i_copy recebe aux, aux é um inteiro, não uma lista, então i_copy deixa de ser uma lista e vira um inteiro, então quando você tenta pegar a próxima posição de i_copy no if `if x < i_copy[y]:`, ele acusa que não tem o atributo responsável pelo item do vetor.

Tente fazer assim.

```
def func(i):
    i_copy = [x for x in i]

    for y in range(len(i)):
        for x in i_copy:
            if x < i[y]:
                i_copy[y] = x
    return i_copy
```

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda, mas não está correta. Para o seguinte input: func ( [1256, 0, 2, -3, 4, 10, 7, 8, 9] ) deveria sair o seguinte output: [-3, 0, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1256], mas em vez disso sai: [9, -3, -3, -3, -3, 9, -3, -3, -3]

Comment: da uma olhada nesse código de ordenação. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Answer (score 0):

O que ocorre é que na primeira vez que seu programa executa a linha 10, o array `i_copy` recebe o valor de `x`. Porém, `x` é apenas um número retirado do mesmo array (vide a linha 6). Então na próxima iteração do laço da linha 6, você tenta utilizar `i_copy`, que agora se tornou um número, como se fosse uma estrutura iterável, gerando a exceção.

Tudo porque na linha 10 você esqueceu de referenciar uma posição específica do array `i_copy`. E de qualquer forma a lógica do seu algoritmo parece estar errada. Segue a minha versão do mesmo algoritmo:

```
1   def func(i):
2       i_copy = []
3       for elem in i:
4           i_copy.append(elem)
5       for y in range(0, len(i_copy)):
6           for x in range(y + 1, len(i_copy)):
7               if i_copy[x] < i_copy[y]:
8                   aux = i_copy[x]
9                   i_copy[x] = i_copy[y]
10                  i_copy[y] = aux
11      return i_copy
```

Perceba como na linha 6 eu não estou iterando sobre cada elemento do vetor, e sim apenas sobre os índices. E com esses índices eu consigo realizar a trocar dos elementos quando apropriado.